# javascript canvas touchstart and touchend not working on touchscreen

Tags: javascript, canvas, touch

Using the phpacademy painting app tutorial, I attempted to add touchscreen support.I have the same code for mouse and touch, however touchup and down are not triggered.

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', engage);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', putPoint);
canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', engage);
canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', putPoint);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', disengage);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', disengage);
canvas.addEventListener('touchend', disengage);
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you use for the handlers? The event object will look a little different for the touch and mouse events. Have you checked with console.log that they don't trigger? And which browsers are you trying with (at least Safari supports touch events with canvas) ?

Comment: http;//joeybabcock.me/tests/php/5.php/ I literally started javascript two days before I posted this. I will attempt to use safari, and than go with the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canvas element doesn't receive the touchstart events (lame I know). In order to get it to work you'll have to hack something up like absolute position a div over the canvas and use the div to catch the touchstart event.

Comment: So something like a div that goes over the whole page?

Comment: I tried that, but it still doesn't work even in chrome and safari.

Comment: Can you make a gist of what you have? Having a div over the canvas is working for me in mobile safari.

Comment: Yeah me too in safari only as of now...I'll give this the answer points, although i wish there was a way to do it in chrome because i hate safari.

Comment: Hrm... it's working for me in mobile chrome. Head to zbabb.com/touchtest.html and just start tapping around. Pull the src from console and see if you can see a difference with what you have.

Comment: Many years later, I thought I had this problem. Turns out I was just bad at reading and was trying to use `"touchup"` instead of `"touchend"`